# Get rowid of locked row in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am carrying out an update on dept table with update query as -

```
update dept set dname = initcap(dname) where deptno=20;
```

As, I have not committed, row lock will be placed on the row. I want to find out the `rowid` of dept table locked from `V$LOCK`.

Currently, I am not able to figure out how to get it. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could execute the following statement before you update:

```
SELECT ROWID AS RID FROM DEPT WHERE DEPTNO = 20 FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: I have simulated the lock. Basically, I want to get the rowid, if the locking is done by application(jdbc call) and I am not aware of the rowid.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: To get the rowsids of table locked by application.

Comment: @SujitPandey. Ok, but what is the purpose of getting the rowid's of the locked rows?

Answer (score 0):

First of query the `V$LOCKED_OBJECT` to get the object_id. Then query `v$open_cursor` to get the `SQL_TEXT`, using this you can get the ROWIDs.

```
SQL> select * from t2 where id=1 for update;

        ID KEY                  VALUE
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 A101                 Athens
```

Run the following commads as `SYSDBA`

```
SQL> select session_id, object_id from v$locked_object;

SESSION_ID  OBJECT_ID
---------- ----------
      1724     213690

SQL> select user_name, sql_text from v$open_cursor where sid=1724;

USER_NAME    SQL_TEXT
---------    ------------------------------------------------------------
JAY          insert into sys.aud$( sessionid,entryid,statement,ntimestamp
JAY          select * from t2 where id=1 for update


SQL> select rowid from jay.t2 where id=1;

ROWID
------------------
AAA0K6AAEAAAACsAAA
```

Oracle doesn't keep track of locked rows. If there are blocked rows then you can get the rowids as shown below.

```
SQL> select dbms_rowid.ROWID_CREATE(1,s.ROW_WAIT_OBJ#,s.ROW_WAIT_FILE#,s.ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#,s.ROW_WAIT_ROW#) rid from v$session s join v$locked_object lo on s.ROW_WAIT_OBJ#=lo.object_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay..If it contains bind (id=:id) value rather than id=1 ?